# Get access to getSupportFragmentManager in non activity class

Tags: android, android-context, fragmentmanager

I hope someone can help.
I have a non activity class in which I need to access the fragmentmanager in a **static** method, unfortunatly I don`t know how to pass the context correctly.

Any help is appreciated,

Non activity class:

```
public class testClass {
..
public synchronized static void checkNewdata(List<data>input, Context context) {
..
       FragmentManager ft = ((FragmentActivity)???).getSupportFragmentManager();
                DialogFragment newFragment = MyNotification.newInstance();
                newFragment.setCancelable(false);
                newFragment.show(ft, "mydialog");
..
   }
}
```

The method checkNewdata is also being called from a non activity class, in which I try to pass context but this doesn`t work:

```
public class SearchResponse extends SuccessResponse {

private Context mcontext;

public SearchResponse(Context context){
    mcontext = context;
}
..
@Override
    public void save() {
..
    testClass.checkNewdata(mainData, context);
..
   }
}
```

Comment: Holding a `Context` reference in a static method is a bad idea. I suggest you to rethink your design rather than searching for a workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass your Activity instead of  Context

```
public synchronized static void checkNewdata(List<data>input, Activity activity) {
..
       FragmentManager ft = ((FragmentActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager();
                DialogFragment newFragment = MyNotification.newInstance();
                newFragment.setCancelable(false);
                newFragment.show(ft, "mydialog");
..
   }
```

Comment: Thx, I used:

private Activity activity;

    public SearchResponse(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

But now the app crashes: Unable to create converter for class..
retrofit.